# Problem with extracting multiple segments

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to capture the bellow parts from the attached log:

```
aff_lsr?tt_adv_id=806&tt_cid=&tt_adv_sub=b3fff3722fc6b52aedde9b86bb22bf23&tt_time=2016-04-05+16%3A08%3A18&
```

should capture:

```
●   tt_adv_id
●   806
●   tt_adv_sub 
●   b3fff3722fc6b52aedde9b86bb22bf23
●   tt_time
●   2016-04-05+16%3A08%3A18
```

I have tried to create a regex to extract all strings which start with either “?” “&” or “=” and end with either “=” or “&”

this is the regex I have tried:

```
(?=[?/&/=]).*?(=)|(?=[=/&])
```

it ignores all parts between “=” and “&”

so the result i get is :

```
?tt_adv_id =

&tt_cid=

&tt_adv_sub=

&tt_time =
```

Comment: the string is always in given format ? it seems as query parameters of URL

Comment: Why `tt_cid` is not included in final result ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, these simple expressions would extract our desired values:

```
.*(tt_adv_id)=([^&]*)&(?:tt_cid)=(?:[^&]*)&(tt_adv_sub)=([^&]*)&(tt_time)=([^&]*).*
```

or

```
(tt_adv_id)=([^&]*)&(?:tt_cid)=(?:[^&]*)&(tt_adv_sub)=([^&]*)&(tt_time)=([^&]*)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/LHolMQ/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/LHolMQ/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

```js
const regex = /.*(tt_adv_id)=([^&]*)&(?:tt_cid)=(?:[^&]*)&(tt_adv_sub)=([^&]*)&(tt_time)=([^&]*).*/gm;
const str = `aff_lsr?tt_adv_id=806&tt_cid=&tt_adv_sub=b3fff3722fc6b52aedde9b86bb22bf23&tt_time=2016-04-05+16%3A08%3A18&
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: hi, do you know how to capture it into 6 different groups ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
/[?&=]([^&=]+)/
```

- `[?&=]` - Match `?, & or =`
- `([^&=]+)` - Match anything except `& and =` one or more time

[image]

and than drop off the first character of each match,

```js
let str = "aff_lsr?tt_adv_id=806&tt_cid=&tt_adv_sub=b3fff3722fc6b52aedde9b86bb22bf23&tt_time=2016-04-05+16%3A08%3A18&"

let matched = str.match(/[?&=]([^&=]+)/g).map((v)=>v.substr(1))

console.log(matched)
```

Comment: Thanks , it works but I do need to 6 different capture groups